# CompareValidator works on local PC but doesn't work on server

Tags: asp.net, comparevalidator

I have added a `CompareValidator` to compare the dates as below:

```
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpFromToTodate" runat="server" CultureInvariantValues="true" 
      ControlToValidate="dtpToDate" ControlToCompare="dtpFromDate"
      ErrorMessage="To Date Should be Greater than or Euqal to From Date"
      Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Type="Date">
```

This works when developing in local PC, but not when I host this page to a server. Here I have added some screenshots.

*Local Browser Screenshot:*
[image: Local Browser Screenshot]

*Screenshot after hosting the page to server:*
[image: Screenshot after hosting the page to server]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think error occur for local and server time format .
Please print server time format and check it.
i hope it help you

Comment: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/UserPanel/User.master" AutoEventWireup="true" UICulture="en-IN" Culture="en-IN"
    CodeFile="Booking.aspx.cs" Inherits="UserPanel_Booking" %>

Comment: added UICulture an Culture as above in page directive and it worked.